# ¿Como Cargar una vista dentro de otra?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando mediante `ajax` hacer un `append` de una vista a otra pero no me funciona estoy trabajando con `php` y el `framework laravel`.

Vista `.blade.php` Principal

```
    <div id="prueba_html">

    </div>
```

Este es mi `controlador.php`

```
public function verificarCuenta(Request $request){


    $data = array();
    $html =  view('user.transacciones_table');
    $data = array_add($data, 'html', $html);

    return $data;
}
```

Esta es la vista que deseo cargar `.blade.php`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <th>Prueba</th>
          <th>Prueba</th>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

al verificar en el `ajax` lo que retorno, un arreglo debido a que envió más variables a la vista cuando hago un `console.log` en mi vista recibo un arreglo vació donde debería estar mi vista.

[image: Vista de lo que retorna la vista]

He intentado en mi `ajax` cargar la vista con `jquery` de las maneras

```
  $("#prueba_html").html(response.html); 
  $("#prueba_html").append(response.html);
```

Sin éxito alguno.

¿Alguien sabe de que manera se puede realizar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con

`$html = View::make('user.transacciones_table')->render()`;

---

Nota: Debes colocoar el namespace de View no el Facade.

Comment: Funciono perfecto!, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada! Siempre a la orden.

Comment: ¿De que manera puedo enviar datos a la vista que deseo cargar?, para luego enviarla con los datos

Comment: Bueno en ese caso el metodo tiene un segundo parametro que corresponde a un array de parametros alli puedes incluirlos.

`$html = View::make('user.transacciones_table', [ 'nombre_variable_en vista' => $data ])->render();`

Ten en cuenta que el nombre que coloques en la key del array es el nombre que tendra en la vista la variable.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!